# PHP fopen error-works on live server but fails on test server

Tags: php, xampp

I am very new to PHP and a beginner programmer. I have struggled with this issue for four days and I am finally posting my first question here for help.

I have built a test environment using XAMPP on my PC and have had good success with developing PHP/HTML content locally and then putting it up live on my hosting company's server.

However I am running into an issue when using PHP fopen to open a text file. It works perfect on the live server but does not work locally on the test server. I get this error on the test server.

> "...failed to open stream: No such file or directory..."

The file I am trying to open exists locally and on the live server in the same relative path from the site root.

I believe the issue is due to the fact that the actual path to the file on my hosting server is different from actual path on my test server. My hosted server company requires I use a specific path just to get to the root of my website when accessing files. It goes something like this:
`/home/users/web/b54321/moo.mysite`

However, the actual PC path to get to my testing domain root is `c:/vhosts/mysite`

I thought I had found the answer myself earlier in that I have to modify the `<IfModule alias_module>` section on my testing environment's httpd.conf file by creating an Alias. I tried that but did not have success. Not sure if I am on the right track but here is what I tried.

`Alias /home/users/web/b54321/moo.mysite  "C:\vhosts\mysite"`

This did not work and after reading more details realized this seems to only be specific to URL's and not PHP file path's.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Sorry if this is a basic question. I have been searching and trying various fixes without a resolution.

Here is the actual Code that works on the live server but fails on the test server. Keep in mind 'climate' is a first level folder on the root of my site.

```
if ($_POST) {
$filename = '/home/users/web/b54321/moo.mysite/climate/noaa/NOAA reports '.$_POST["year"].'/'.$_POST["year"].'_'.$_POST["month"].'.txt';
 $fd = fopen ($filename, "r");

 $contents2 = fread ($fd,filesize ($filename));
 $contents = str_replace(" ","&nbsp",$contents2);

 fclose ($fd);
```

Comment: So I can't believe it. After struggling with this for the last four days I may have answered my own question. I did find a post that may have helped. I think what I should be doing is using this piece of code.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to get me to my site root. I can then navigate from there. I tried this and it works now on the testing and production server. Let me know if this is a good fix and if there are any possible pitfalls by using this method.

Comment: Should be fine. You ought to post your own answer below with your complete solution, then return in a couple of days when you're allowed to and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] however if you put your code in a different folder then it will break.  See below

Instead of that you could just define your own variable for the folder root.  That way when you move your code to a new server, just update the variable, preferably in a common config.inc.php file.

> On Server 1 You host your code at a domain like
> http://www.mycoolsite.com/  (using the web server root)
>
> $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] would be
> '/home/users/web/b54321/moo.mysite/';
> $folderroot='/home/users/web/b54321/moo.mysite/';

Everything works great with either option.

On a different machine it could be

> On Server 2 You host your code at a domain and url like
> http://www.myotherwebsite.com/noaa_stuff/
>
> $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
> would be something like '/home/users/web/ss22/moo.mytotherwebsite/';
>
> But that's not including the 'noaa_stuff' folder
>
> So you set
>
> $folderroot='/home/users/web/ss22/moo.mytotherwebsite/noaa_stuff/';

On Server 2.  Your DOCUMENT_ROOT system would probably cause some errors on finding files.  But setting folderroot to the exact folder makes it easy.